# Regex to Capture and replace

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have URL like this

- http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2148xg_brazil-1-7-germany-brazil-player-ratings-from-a-shocking-defeat_sport

I need to capture a text **`video`** and replace it with **`swf`** as follows:

- http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/x2148xg_brazil-1-7-germany-brazil-player-ratings-from-a-shocking-defeat_sport

If i use normal string.Replace, then it will replace the video text which may contained in file name of video, So i want to capture a **`video`** after **`domain`** and replace it with **`swf`**

Please help me out..

I have tried this `^(http:\/\/(?:www.)?(?:dailymotion).com\/)\?(video)$` but dont know how much is it right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search `(http://\S+/)video(/\S+)`, replace with `$1swf$2`

**In VB.NET:**

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(http://\S+/)video(/\S+)", "$1swf$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

**Explanation**

- The regex matches the string in three parts: Group 1, `video`, Group 2, and we replace that with Group 1, `swf`, Group 2
- `(http://\S+/)` captures to Group 1 `http//`, any chars that are not a white-space, and a forward slash
- `video` matches literal characters
- `(/\S+)` captures to Group 2 any chars that are not white-space characters

Comment: Thank +1...It seems working before that i shoud get domain name..I have used `^(?:http:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.(?:com|net|org|info|biz|mobi|us|ly)$` but not working

Comment: Not understanding what you need to change to the code, can you please explain? The code I gave you should replace `video` inside the url, regardless of the domain. See the substitutions at the bottom of [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/49)

Comment: yes that's fine. no problem in it.. i need new regex to capture a domain from url , like youtube from www.youtube.com and dailymotion from http:www.dailymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regexes and replace the second capturing group with `swf`,

```
^(http:\/\/(?:www\.)?dailymotion\.com\/)([^\/]*)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qH4pC6/2)

OR

```
^(http:\/\/(?:www\.)?dailymotion\.com\/)(video)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qH4pC6/3)

From starting, characters upto the string `.com/` are captured by the first the group. Next the characters upto the next forward slash are captured by second group(ie, `video`). All the remaining characters are captured by third group. Just replacing the second captured group in your case it's `video` with `swf` will  give you the desired result.